# Conditional counting of consecutive rows

Tags: ms-access, vba

For a given current client i am trying to find how many consecutive years they have renewed a policy with us. My thinking on how to do this is to match a field in the current row with the previous row. I'm trying to write a function for this but if there is an easier way please let me know. Here is what i have for the function

```
Option Compare Database
'Renewal Count Returns count of consecutive renewals
Public Function RenewCount(strLocationID As Integer, _
                   strQuoteID As Integer, _
                   strOriginalQuoteID As Variant) As String
Static strLastLocationID As Integer
Static strLastQuoteID As Integer
Static strCount As Integer
If strLocationID = strLastLocationID And strOriginalQuoteID = strLastQuoteID Then
    strCount = strCount + 1
Else
    strLastLocationID = strLocationID
    strLastQuoteID = strQuoteID
    strCount = 0

End If
RenewCount = strCount
End Function
```

Here is a little sample of the data

```
LocationID  QuoteID OriginalQuoteID
2            1094117    
2            1125718    1094117
2            1148296    1125718
2            1176466    1148296
5            1031892   
5            1044976    1031892
5            1059216    1044976
5            1077463    1059216
```

There are also dates for each policy that i can manipulate as well. 
My idea would be to have the following and just find the max of the last column for each location.

```
LocationID  QuoteID OriginalQuoteID Renewal_Count
2            1125718    1094117       0
2            1148296    1125718       1
2            1176466    1148296       2
5            1031892                  0
5            1044976    1031892       1
5            1059216    1044976       2
5            1077463    1059216       3
5            1098124    1077463       4
5            1100215                  0
5            1198714    1100215       1
5            1254125    1198714       2
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I forgot to mention that this has been sorted on the location ID and that OriginalQuoteID will be null for any New policy. When i try to run the function i get #num! in the column for a majority of the rows. What i want is for a given QuoteID the number of consecutive renewals there have been. So for the above for locationID 5 QuoteID 1254125 there have been 2 Renewals.

Comment: How do you know if the renewals are consecutive?

Comment: I forgot to mention that OriginalQuoteID is null on the first year of the policy. Every year after if it is a renewal the OriginalQuoteID has the QuoteID from the previous year.

Comment: Not so sure my answer below is working as expected - it works off of `LocationID` at the moment.  In your comment you say *is null on the first year* in your post you say *can be null* - which is it?  First year is always Null - which gives a definite start point, or can be null which makes the start point more ambiguous.

Comment: Yes the first year is always null. I've been trying to format my reply to your comment but the results still show on a single line. Basically what I want is for a given set of QuoteIDs how many consecutive renewals has there been up to that quoteID.

Answer (score 0):

This might work (appears to be with my tests) - create a cartesian product on itself, link the QuoteID to the OriginaQuoteID and count.

```
SELECT  T1.LocationID,
        T1.QuoteID,
        T1.OriginalQuoteID
FROM    Table1 T1, Table1 T2
WHERE   T1.QuoteID = T2.OriginalQuoteID
```

to get the count per LocationID (add 1 to count the Null field):

```
SELECT      COUNT(*)+1
FROM        Table1 T1, Table1 T2
WHERE       T1.QuoteID = T2.OriginalQuoteID
GROUP BY    T1.LocationID
```

or if you prefer joins:

```
SELECT      COUNT(*)+1
FROM        Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON T1.QuoteID = T2.OriginalQuoteID
GROUP BY    T1.LocationID
```